# adb "CreateProcess Failure, error 5"

Tags: adb, windows

When I want to test an app in Eclipse (in an AVD), it throws out the following:

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\[...]\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

The problem is, the file is actually there and CAN be executed.
When I open cmd and go to that path and type "**adb start-server**", I get following error message:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
CreateProcess failure, error 5
* failed to start daemon *
```

After a reboot, process kill, reinstalling Eclipse and all SDKs, trying without antivirus, the problem still persists. I've also looked up the port 5037, which is not blocked by any program.

Comment: I have UAC turned on, but I also tried it in a CMD with admin privileges. The solution from "bmdixon" actually worked, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674517/785750) answer on stack overflow suggests that it could be a permissions issue, the user that is attempting to start the adb server cannot access the file. Could you try moving the sdk to a folder that is not within your users area and see if you can start it then?

Comment: wow. I'm speechless. Wouldn't have thought it's something that simple.
Thank you!